UnknownCurrencyException: Unknown currency code: foo
I am using Moneta 1.4, and have included in my classpath :

moneta-core-1.4.4.jar
money-api-1.1.jar

I was checking classpath, and I've seen (also in documentation) that Moneta uses ServiceProviders functionality from Java language, to extend money-api functionality.
The thing is, randomly, and let's say in a 5% of the times, when I try to use FastMoney.of(), I get the exception below.
Simple call that fails sometime:
amount = FastMoney.of(
    amount.value,
    amount.currency,
),

The exception (Mind the line numbers please)
"exception": "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception javax.money.UnknownCurrencyException: Unknown currency code: foo [in thread \"Thread-572\"]
        at javax.money.spi.MonetaryCurrenciesSingletonSpi.getCurrency(MonetaryCurrenciesSingletonSpi.java:78)
        at javax.money.Monetary.getCurrency(Monetary.java:382)\n\tat org.javamoney.moneta.FastMoney.<clinit>(FastMoney.java:119)

Any idea why this could be happening? I am concerned that it fails randomly so I can not control it.
I've checked rhe code and I presume, as DefaultMonetaryCurrenciesSingletonSpi::getDefaultProviderChain() returns a list of providers in an ARBITRARY order, some provider I have may not recognize the "no currency code", but sadly can not prove that.
I expect FastMoney.of(1, "EUR") to always work.

Have you printed the value amount.currency

If it happens only some of the time, that implies a threading issue.  Are you using multiple threads?

Is the XXX part of the real stacktrace or is that just a value that you put there as an example value?

Hi @f1sh, yep, XXX is exactly part of stackTrace.
I doubt it is some thread issue, as I am not doing concurrent programming when caling Fastmoney.of

In that case it looks like wherever you are getting your input from should be checked. That input seems to contain a currency code of XXX, which is invalid.

"The code XXX is used to denote a "transaction" involving no currency." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#X_currencies_(funds,_precious_metals,_supranationals,_other)

Can you link to the documentation that you mentioned? I cannot find it.

What exactly do you mean by ServiceProviders? Do you mean Service provider interface (SPI)?

As user VGR notes "If it happens only some of the time, that implies a threading issue."
Here is a suggestion that might work in case concurrency turns out to be the problem:
(You state that you are doing any concurrency when calling FastMoney.of but it might be worth a try anyway.)
Make sure that the FastMoney class is loaded immediately when the program is started. That means first of all in the main method, or something similar depending on what framework you are using.
To make sure a class is loaded do this:
Call any method on the class. Static or instance.
For example, you could add this at the top of your main method:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Dummy call to initialize the class to avoid ExceptionInInitializerError
    // due to concurrency bug in Java Money library
    FastMoney.of(1, "EUR"); 
    // ... continue with normal code ...
}

Explanation
In Java the initialisation of classes are done when the classes are loaded. Classes are normally loaded lazily when they are first used. Code to initialize static fields and initialiser blocks and are run at this time.
Maybe Java Money has a bug in its initialisation code that creates an error depending on which thread that performs the initialisation.
By making sure that the class is initialized before any extra threads are started maybe you can avoid the bug.
(This is not very likely but worth a try.)
